# Regular level set theorem proof, manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

Let $F:N\rightarrow M$ be a smooth map between manifolds of dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively. A non-empty regular level set $F^{-1}(c)$ where $c\in M$ is a submanifold of $N$ of dimension equal to $n-m$.

The proof starts of by something like this:

Choose a chart $(V,\psi)=(V,y^1,.....,y^m)$ centred about $c$. By continuity of smooth maps, $F^{-1}(V)$ is an open set in $N$ that contains $F^{-1}(c)$. In $F^{-1}(V)$, $F^{-1}(c)=(\psi \circ F)^{-1}(\textbf{0})$.

However the part I don't understand is the following:

In $F^{-1}(V)$, $F^{-1}(c)$ is the common zero set of the functions $r^i \circ (\psi \circ F)$, where $r^i$ is the standard coordinates on euclidean space.

How do I actually prove that?

Comment: What does $(\psi \circ F)^{-1}(\mathbf{0})$ mean? It's the set of points $n$ where $\psi(F(n)) = \mathbf{0}$. What does it mean to have $\psi(F(n)) = \mathbf{0}$? Well, it just means that each coordinate of $\psi(F(n))$ is $0$. In other words, $r^i(\psi(F(n))) = 0$ for all $i$. So, for any $n \in N$, we have $n \in F^{-1}(c) = (\psi \circ F)^{-1}(\mathbf{0})$ if and only if $r^i(\psi(F(n))) = 0$ for all $i$, if and only if $n \in \bigcap_i (r^i \circ \psi \circ F)^{-1}(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading my comment to an answer:

We wish to show that $F^{-1}(c)$ is the common zero set of the functions $r^i \circ \psi \circ F$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, m\}$. In other words, we want

$$F^{-1}(c) = \bigcap_{i = 1}^m (r^i \circ \psi \circ F)^{-1}(0).$$

We already know that $F^{-1}(c) = (\psi \circ F)^{-1}(\mathbf{0})$, and of course $\{\mathbf{0}\} = \bigcap_{i=1}^m (r^i)^{-1}(0)$. Thus,

$$F^{-1}(c) = (\psi \circ F)^{-1}(\{\mathbf{0}\}) = (\psi \circ F)^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^m (r^i)^{-1}(0)\right) = \bigcap_{i=1}^m (\psi \circ F)^{-1}((r^i)^{-1}(0)) = \bigcap_{i=1}^m (r^i \circ \psi \circ F)^{-1}(0),$$

as desired.

Comment: OH, it's the intersection. I didn't understand that it was the intersection, I assumed it was the zero set of each, $\textbf{individual}$ smooth map, $ F^i$.

Comment: "Common zero set" means "the set where all of the functions are simultaneously zero".

Comment: Right, I thought it meant that the zero set of each individual $ F^i$ was $F^{-1}(c)$, which is clearly non-sense. It was a language issue.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Glad I could clear it up!